# php and mysql database problem with only displaying the data the user entered into the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website where a user who has already logged in can enter in text notes. Once the user has entered in the text notes, the information is sent and stored in one of mysql databases that I have. Additionally, the text notes are printed out on the webpage (fetched the data from the database and echoed it). However, I'm able to see the same text notes printed on the webpage from a logged in user on another logged in users account. In simpler terms, users notes are being printed on all users accounts.

However, I only want the specific logged in user to only see his text notes and not others users.

I'm pretty new to php and mysql, so I was wondering if anyone understands what I'm trying to accomplish and can point me in the right direction.

This is a pretty vague question and may be hard to visualize without pictures or code, so I apologize.

Comment: Update the select query that reads the notes so that it has a where clause which limits the results to those notes owned by the currently logged-in user.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I currently have 2 databases. 1 that stores login information and 1 that stores notes information. So how would I use the select query across multiple databases?

Comment: Does the notes table have a field to indicate the user who authored the note?

Comment: @AlexHowansky no it does not. I have 5 fields. The 5 fields include things like the id (number) of the note, title of the note, type of note (school, work, other, etc), note contents, etc. The only unique identifier I have for the user is their email which is in the login database. With that being said I was thinking about having the user also enter in their email but I feel like that's impractical to make the user constantly enter in their email. From there, I could verify the users email, and do a WHERE email = $['email'] to only print out information that was given by that email, right?

Comment: @AlexHowansky my select query for my notes database for now reads as  <?php $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notes_info"); ?>

Comment: You will need to add a field to the notes table to identify the user that wrote the note. The email address will suffice for this purpose if that's all you have, but a numerical id would be better if you have one on the users table. You don't need to prompt the user to add their email each time, because if they're logged in, then you _already_ know who they are. Just include the logged-in user's email address (or id) in the insert statement when you create a note record.